# SocketError: Socket was remotely closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, push-notification

Getting error in apnotic gem

```
connection = Apnotic::Connection.new(cert_path: Rails.public_path + "dev_ck.pem")

  # create a notification for a specific device token
  token = "5F2822CBF606487BA11CA364C4B35893A639..."
  notification       = Apnotic::Notification.new(token)
  notification.alert = "Notification from Apnotic!"
  notification.sound = ''
  notification.badge = 1
  notification.topic = 'testing'
  # send (this is a blocking call)
  response = connection.push(notification)
```

It gives socket error

Comment: Does it give any especial error code? Please add it to the question

Comment: Me I just get Socket was remotely closed

Comment: Upgrade your gem. Apple change http2 header order. See https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic/issues/73#issuecomment-406061963